# How can I Insert images into .rnw document

Tags: r, sweave, latex

I work in R and deliver PDF file with Sweave, `sweave(.rnw document)`. I need to put into my text a JPEG image. I didn't find any function on the web and have no ideas about how I could do that.

Answer (score 6):

You include it just like you include an image in any other LaTeX document:

http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/figures.html#pdf

```
\includegraphics{myimage.jpg}
```

Put it in a LaTeX block not an R code block.  As the link points out, you'll need to compile with `pdflatex`.